# Tefila (prayer) translation Hebrew to English

Tags: shabbat, product-recommendation, internet, shacharis-morning-prayer, english

Are there any websites of Hebrew-to-English translation of shacharis (morning prayer) for Shabbos? What I really want is the English translation to be right under the Hebrew text. Kind of like Artscroll's interlinear Siddurim.

Comment: Hello "Chaim" and welcome to Mi Yodeya. If you haven’t done so already, you should take a look at the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour). I hope you'll look around and find other Q&A of interest and stay learning with us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that [this](http://www.kakatuv.com/orthodox.html) might be of use.